# Error in syntac ZPL string into byte spooler print

Tags: java, barcode, zpl

I can't resolved this syntax:

```
printerConnection.write(configLabel = "^FO80,160 ^BY1,2.0,180^BCN,180,Y,N,N^FD" + nor + "^FS".getBytes());//error in here

printerConnection.write(configLabel = "^FO250,400 ^A0,38,38^FD" + name + "^FS" .getBytes());//error in here

printerConnection.write(configLabel = "^XZ".getBytes())


 //its Query for input to syntax ZPL 

sql1= "SELECT  norm as a1, "
+ "name as a "
+ "from xytable"
+ "where nor ="+noRParameter+" ";
java.sql.Statement stmt=koneksi.createStatement();
java.sql.ResultSet rslt=stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
while(rslt.next()){
String nor = rslt.getString("nor");
String name = rslt.getString("name");}
```

I got error in script ZPL. It's byte but I got data in string? Can you help me? Thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the getBytes() method only on the last string.
You need something like:

```
printerConnection.write(
   // Note the added parents around the String you want to execute getBytes() on.
   configLabel = ("^FO80,160 ^BY1,2.0,180^BCN,180,Y,N,N^FD" + nor + "^FS").getBytes()
);
```